# Ctrl-h mapping in Neovim's terminal emulator

Tags: terminal, neovim

I've enabled the following mappings in my `init.vim`:

```
tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>
tnoremap <C-h> <C-\><C-n><C-w>h
tnoremap <C-j> <C-\><C-n><C-w>j
tnoremap <C-k> <C-\><C-n><C-w>k
tnoremap <C-l> <C-\><C-n><C-w>l

nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

These greatly improve windows navigation in Vim.

However, I've noticed that `C-h` does not work as expected when executed in terminal buffer. Trying this on a usual terminal session results in `Backspace` action. So probably it seems to be one of these alternative key combinations, like `C-i` for `Tab` or `C-[` for `Esc`. But is there any way to make `C-h` work in Neovim's terminal session as per my bindings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has already been extensively debated [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2048). Original Vim does not rely on `terminfo` and includes its own patch for correct handling of `C-h` sequences. Neovim does look at `terminfo` though.

Briefly, the fix is executing these commands in the shell:

```
infocmp $TERM | sed 's/kbs=^[hH]/kbs=\\177/' > $TERM.ti
tic $TERM.ti
```